# Shorter way to do this challenge?

Tags: java

Basically, I am getting ready for an interview and following a regime that gives me a bunch of challenges that are often thrown in interviews.

This particular challenge's goal is to count the number of words that appear more than once in a sentence excluding punctuations. I did it but it took me at least 5 minutes to come up with it and code it.

I'm not sure if taking 5 minutes is acceptable to code something like this in java interviews so I would like to see something simpler with maybe less code. Below is how I solved it.

```
    System.out.println("Part 6 challenge-------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    String sentence3 = "She's the queen and likes, apples APPLES, bananas BANANAS Bananas, and oranges ORANGE."; //original string
    StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder(); //declared string builder to build new string without punctuations
    char [] punctuations = {'.',',',':','?','!',';'};//Char array containing punctuations to lookout for
    for (int i=0; i<sentence3.length(); i++){
        boolean p = false; //declared boolean within loop to turn on if punctuation was found in the original string
        for (Character c: punctuations){
            if (sentence3.charAt(i) == c){
                p = true;// turn on
            }
        } if(!p){
            sb3.append(sentence3.charAt(i));//if no punctuations found, add it to the string builder to build new string
        }
    }
    String word[] = sb3.toString().split(" ");
    Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<>();
    int count = 0;

    for (String s: word) {
        uniqueWords.add(s.toLowerCase());
    }
    for (String s: uniqueWords){
        for (String w: word){
            if (s.equals(w.toLowerCase())){
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Found %s %d times", s, count));
        count =0;
    }
```

Comment: Remember that coding challenges of this sort are usually red flags. Companies that use coding tests self-select for employees that are good at coding tests, not production code.

Comment: Probably better suited for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @tadman why are they red flags?

Comment: Personally, I would take more than that :)
But I think if the solution is correct and you are within the time frame (if any) ,then thats what matters, IMHO.

Comment: In your day to day job you'll typically be tackling large, difficult problems and some of those can take weeks to figure out and months to implement. These "quick, reverse a red-black tree" type questions test all the wrong things. You can solve puzzles all day but be useless as a coder because you're lack focus, motivation, or can't work on a team.

Comment: If I were reviewing this code, I'd ask for separate methods for sentence splitting, for counting, and the main method. If you can explain way, you'd have an extra point from me; if not, it's separation of concerns, testability, reusability, at least. Also, doing the thing with streams could be even more straightforward; consider it.

Comment: Also, I myself would care more about the robustness of the solution than the time you provided it..

Comment: @tadman: I mildly disagree. While mind-bending puzzlers are rare, mundane code is full of trivial-looking tasks like this (chop some data, shuffle and re-assemble it differently). A short piece of code lets you show that you can code, can code cleanly, understand and can explain what you have done and why, and is a good starting point to many deeper conversations (e.g. performance, or patterns / approaches, different tools, etc). That is, if you're looking for a job of a developer who is paid for thinking and solving problems, not a "coder".

Comment: @9000 When you're hiring a civil engineer to build bridges do you give them a bunch of popsicle sticks and some glue and make them build a bridge? The tech industry has a lot of absurd rituals and coding in interviews is one of the most ridiculous. Ask to see some of their code before hand if they can provide it. If they can't, get them to review some code you or your team has written so you can judge how well they can understand it. There's many better methods to get a good assessment of how a candidate will perform in the real world.

Comment: @tadman: A civil engineer worth their salt will tell you which configuration of popsicle sticks is more stable than others, under what kind of load, and can explain why. Trivial tasks like the above are _utterly_ practical in my current area (data analysis), and understanding how to do them in a few lines is important. The piece of code I've seen _already_ showed me a lot about the candidate's areas of weakness, and would make a great conversation piece should I interview him/her. Many silly rituals exist, but solving small, easy-to-understand, non-contrived code challenges is not one of them.

Comment: @9000 I'm not sure any civil engineer would be prepared to tell you that without knowing the characteristics of the sticks involved and the properties of the glue. I'm not sure the popsicle stick company publishes a reference sheet with sufficient detail. The exercise is entirely ridiculous, just as most coding exercises are. Life isn't a series of trivial requests, even if in some more narrow domains it might seem like it.

Comment: Yeah, I failed my interview test :( I had 20 similar challenges to do with only 1h30m. I could do most  of them but needed more time :(. Especially the one that gave me a hex to convert to dec then convert it to roman numerals. Hex -> dec is relatively simple but I don't even understand roman numerals completly :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shorter way, outlined:

- Split by regexp;
- Filter for words (may be not needed depending on your regexp);
- Replace `Set<String>` with a `Map<String, Integer>` and count word quantities in linear time;
- Filter out and output words with count > 1.

BTW this can *all* be one stream expression if you're into minimal statement count.